# Facet Enumeration Problem nondegeneracy case

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-hulls

Hello in case of a nondegeneracy case of the Facet Enumeration Problem, there is a polynomial algorithm for the convex hull problem as written here https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/polyfaq/node18.html .
So the number of facets needs to be bounded by polynominal, so what is maximal number of facets in the nondegeneracy case?

Comment: See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_bound_theorem and https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-11-spring/notes/upper_bound_theorem.pdf.